# calculate days from a column to today in r

Tags: data-mining, dataset, data-cleaning

I have data set with a **Date** column, now i am trying to calculate duration in days from today to dates in date column with a new column named duration. 
I tried

```
    duration <- today() - sales$Date
```

But is giving errors
What is the best way to it?

Comment: Check the format of dates in the sales$Date column of your data. It must be in the same format of dates returned by today().